# is it possible to use a $q promise in a service's dependencies to force the service to wait until the promise is loaded?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-service

I'd like to be able to build a User service that depends on a utility library (that contains a logger and lodash). The code I have seems very close:

```
  angular.module("NS.services").service "utilService", ($window, $q) ->
    console.log 'loading util service'
    util = ->
      deferred = $q.defer()
      require(["cdn-lodash"], (lodash) =>
        console.log 'deferred resolve'
        # I plan on using a more complex logger down the road, so it'd probably be
        # in another require
        deferred.resolve(lib: lodash, logger: $window.logger if $window.logger?)
      )
      deferred.promise

    util: util

  angular.module("NS.services").service "userService", ['$http','utilService', 
  ($http, util) ->
    @get = (id, onError, onSuccess) ->
      throw 'no id supplied' unless id?
      util.logger.debug 'getting user for id' + id
      $http.get("/api/user/#{id}")
        .success (users) ->
          util.logger.debug 'loaded users'
          onSuccess(users)
        .error onError
  ]
```

The problem is that the the `userService` doesn't wait for the Promise to resolve before it fires off the `get` method -- things aren't happening in the order that I want. I thought about wrapping the `@get` method in a require, but that seems clunky and a poor case of reuse.

How can I get `userService` to wait for `utilService` to finish its promise before building itself?

Comment: Might be my lack of knowledge in Coffeescript, but where are you calling the `this.get` method of the service? Also, your `utilService` seems to return an object `{util: util}`, in which case it should be `.factory` not `.service`.

Comment: No worries. The get is being called when the page loads. I don't know that services can't return objects since all of mine return objects that just have functions. Still, the sample that I'm looking at _was_ a factory so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you userService wants to "wait" on the promise, it should call the "then" method of the promise. It does not look like that is currently happening.

Comment: I'd like it to be a bit more implicit than that, but yeah I can use `service = toolsFactory.getTools().then( (tools) =>` etc. and I got that to work. Still, it seems like angular should understand that the service is a promise and wait for it to resolve before calling it "loaded".